# WebBrowser and Excel instance

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, excel-interop

I use a `WebBrowser` control to open an Excel file.

The problem is that if there is already an open Excel instance before, the WebBrowser uses the same instance of Excel (Application).

Is there a method to indicate that the WebBrowser should create a new instance of Excel?

Or is it possible to force (or prevent) new Excel files to open in a specific instance?

Answer (score 0):

If to start files from command line, option /e helps to start them in new instances. For example `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE" /e Book2.xlsx`. If command line is not an option, windows registry can help. Just change it as explained [here](https://conetrix.com/Blog/how-to-open-each-excel-spreadsheet-in-a-new-instance) and [here](http://www.dannyeckes.com/open-excel-2010-in-separate-windows/):

> 1. start -> run -> regedit
> 2. Go to  HKEY_CLASSES_ ROOT/ Excel.Sheet.8/ shell/Open/command
> 3. Double Click on (Default) and write "C:\Program Files\Microso Oﬃce\Oﬃce12 \EXCEL.EXE" /e "% 1" for Oﬃce 2007 or "C:\Program
>      Files\Microso Oﬃce\Oﬃce14 \EXCEL.EXE" /e "% 1" for Oﬃce 2010.
> 4. Right Click on Command, choose "rename", and add something to the name (for example 2 (command2))
> 5. Go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Excel.Sheet.8/ shell/Open/ ddeexec
> 6. Right Click on the folder ddeexec, choose "rename", and add something to the name (for example 2 (ddeexec2))
> 7. Go to HKEY_CLASSES_RO OT/Excel.Sheet.12/ shell/Open/command
> 8. Double Click on (Default) and write "C:\Program Files\Microso Oﬃce\Oﬃce12 \EXCEL.EXE" /e "% 1" for Oﬃce 2007 or  "C:\Program
>      Files\Microso Oﬃce\Oﬃce14 \EXCEL.EXE" /e "% 1" for Oﬃce 2010.
> 9. Right Click on Command, choose "rename", and add something to the name  (for example 2 (command2)).

Or change options of Excel itself, as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/21602/open-excel-files-in-new-window).